# Let $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ be sequences bounded above. prove $\limsup (a_n + b_n)\le \limsup(a_n) +\limsup(b_n)$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble starting this proof from the definition I know that there exists a limit point $x$ such that $M \ge x > M- \frac \epsilon2$ but not quite sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, we have
$$\sup_{k\geqslant n}(a_k+b_k) \leqslant \sup_{k\geqslant n}a_k + \sup_{k\geqslant n}b_k,$$
as $$\{a_k+b_k : k\geqslant n\}\subset \{a_k+b_l:k,l\geqslant n\}$$
and $A\subset B$ implies $\sup A\leqslant\sup B$. Hence
$$\begin{align*}\limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geqslant n}(a_k+b_k)\\&\leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geqslant n}a_k+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geqslant n}b_k\\ &= \limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n.\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

If they represent $\gamma, \alpha$ and $\beta$ correspondingly and if $\gamma \gt \alpha+\beta$, then there should be m such that $\alpha+\beta\lt a_m +b_m \le\gamma$ which means $(\alpha-a_m)+(\beta-b_m)\lt 0$.